# Change color of the text in a cell

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

This is my page and the red text is the `id` of the cell. Below there is an input with `0099CC` which is a color of course and I'd like to apply that color to those cells. When I click the button `Apply` this code is called:

```
function tab1h(color) {
  for(var j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
    document.getElementById('indiv'+j+'_1').style.color = '#'+color;
  }
 }
```

By the way anything happens, I still see those 0 with the white color (instead of blue). Do you have any idea?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3jez/)

Comment: provide jsfiddle link

Comment: Are we supposed to guess your HTML, or did you want to show it? And then, maybe, get some useful answers?

Comment: Is the function really called? Does `document.getElementById(…)` return a non-null result? Add some `console.log`s to see what’s going on.

Comment: This is the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/n3jez/

Comment: Wonderful, now add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In JSFiddle, you need to set the JavaScript configuration to *“No wrap – in `<head>`”* if you want to access the function from your HTML.
2. Your ids are not `indivX_1`but `indivX_2`.

Answer (score 0):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2xrBb/)

*Javascript Code*

```
function changeColor() {
    var color = document.getElementById("txtColor").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
    for (var i = 0; i<=2 ; i++) {
        table.rows[i].cells[0].style.color = '#' + color;
    }
}
```

Set the number of rows you want to change, like in your case you want to change 6 rows so it would be `i<=5` *or* `i<6`.